# How to optimize a flash game?

Tags: flash, actionscript

In my flash game, i have many loops bullets, enemies, objects and other stuff, and those objects have their on animation also, so the game are getting slower if there are many objects, is there a way to make it work faster?

Comment: there are 100 bullets flying and each bullet is looping each 100 enemies checking of collision...i don't know if there is a better way to do this

Comment: Not sure if this is feasible/doable for you, but you could consider using something like Starling (http://gamua.com/starling/). It's hardware-accelerated, so your sprites will render using the underlying GPU (whatever it is) on your platform, instead of using Flash's slow s/w rendering. And also check out nape (http://napephys.com/) for fast collision-detection.

Answer (score 0):

This is too general qustion. You can optimize your grafics - minimize vectors in each shape. Mark export as bitmap option for MovieClips. Reduce mask, alphas and layers. Use "Show redraw option in FP" to see if any unnecesery redraws are hapens. In code - reuse objects , avoid creating objects in loops. You can split some logic accross multiple enter frames. You can use workers. The qustion is too general to get a simple answer. 
Check this articles:
[link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/using/WSd60f23110762d6b883b18f10cb1fe1af6-7b23a.html)
and this [link](http://www.nbilyk.com/optimizing-actionscript-3)